# $this->CI->load->vars($new) values to access on a controler

Tags: php, codeigniter

Below is my code in codeigniter. Which I load through a library

```
$new['maintenance'] = 'No';
$this->CI->load->vars($new);
```

I can access this value in a view file just by

```
echo $maintenance
  // result 'No'
```

I'm trying to do the same in a controller but I can't. If I dump "$this->load" I see the array but I can't access it. How can I print or access this value in a controller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can return the variable to controller from library and load it in view

Answer (score 0):

In your library return the value like

```
$new = 'No';
return $new;
```

And in your controller write like

```
$new['maintenance'] = $this->library_name->function_name();
$this->load->view('view_name',$new);
```

Comment: what I load in the library is big array. not just once value. I can access this on the view but I can't access on the controller. I'm trying to do a if statement this this value on the controller.

Comment: Then dont reference in the array eg $new = $this->library_name->function_name(); and then  $new will be exactly the same as the array your lib function is returning